# Gradle test filter doesn't work for complex test task

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, junit, testng

I have a project with unit tests.
We decided to migrate from testng to JUnit 5 but do it in a couple of iterations.
And now in our project tests for both platforms are present.

I handle it using the following build script:

```
def commonTestConfig =
{
    ignoreFailures = true

    ...
}

task testNGTests(type: Test) {
    useTestNG()
    configure commonTestConfig
    reports.html.destination = file("$buildDir/reports/testng")
}

task junitTests(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform() 
    configure commonTestConfig
    reports.html.destination = file("$buildDir/reports/junit")
}


test {
    dependsOn testNGTests
    dependsOn junitTests
}
```

But if I try to run specific test from command line then build fails:

```
call gradle --warning-mode all test --tests my.package.LicenseTests 
Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
Task :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
Task :testNGTests UP-TO-DATE
Task :junitTests UP-TO-DATE
Task :test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':test'.
No tests found for given includes: [my.package.LicenseTests](--tests filter)
```

I.e. the command above runs all tests(tasks testNGTests and junitTests) without applying provided filter.
And after that tries to find tests to run in **test** task where no any one are supposed to run.

Is there a way to run both JUnit 5 and testng tests in Gradle cleanly, in a way preserving possibility to pass test filter from command line?

Comment: hi, 6 month ago, but... did you try the test filters inside the gradle task? here is some docs https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_filtering

Comment: Hi!
I know that way. 
But the question is about different scenario.

I want to pass test filter from a command line(i.e. I need to configure filter using command line only)
This filter is passed gratefully to test task, but it isn't passed to dependent tasks testNGTests and junitTests...

Is there a way to do it?